# Azure App Service continuous deployment from Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I've setup an Azure App Service which uses a Docker image stored in Azure Container Registry. The ACR uses Basic SKU.

Inside the App Service's Container settings I've turned on the Continuous Deployment settings. When it is connected to ACR there is no webhook like in DockerHub.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to deploy new images when I push them into the repository.

Do I need to setup anything beside turning on the Continuous Deployment setting?

Under the Continuous Deployment section of App Service there is a notice: `Continuous Deployment of Azure Container Registry hosted images requires use of the Azure Container Registry SKU.` but it's really not clear what SKU is required?

When I restart the app I can see in the docker logs that it is running the latest image but I had to restart the app manually to see it.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous deployment feature flag in App Service tells App Service to restart/re-pull when it receives a webhook. It's basically an off switch to disable webhook notifications.
You still need to configure the webhook. Within the geo-replication walkthrough, we use automated deployments to describe how to set this up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-prepare-registry
We are working on making this easier, but this sets up the flow for an ACR Push Webhook that calls App Service